# Get the maximum value of the field Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am trying to get the maximum/highest value available in my collections.

I am trying get the highest salary of the employee collection. We are using Morphia framework.

```
 Query<Employee> query = mongoDatastore.find(Employee.class).field("salary").....
```

//Get the maximum salary available in employee collection.

I am trying to get the maximum salary of the employee collection.

Can some one help me to how to get the highest salary of employee collection.

Comment: loop through and store max isn't a choice??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the highest salary of employee collection, use a combination of the **[order](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#sort)** method to sort the collection by salary descending and **[limit](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#limit)** method to return the top 1 document:

```
Query<Employee> query = mongoDatastore.find(Employee.class).order("-salary").field("salary").limit(1)
```